# Audio cuts out and in after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, external-soundcard

After upgrading to 20.04 my sound will cut out to total silence and then back after a second or less, no matter if using CD, audio file, video file or streaming.  I noticed that with the sound settings window open, the Output Device will change from "line Out-Built-in Audio" to "Headphones-Built-in Audio" when the sound stops and then back to line out when the sound returns.  I tried the command: systemctl --user status pulseaudio and get this output at the end:
Jul 04 10:15:59 roger-desktop systemd[1502]: Starting Sound Service...
Jul 04 10:16:15 roger-desktop pulseaudio[1516]: Failed to open cookie file '/ho>
Jul 04 10:16:15 roger-desktop pulseaudio[1516]: Failed to load authentication k>
Jul 04 10:16:15 roger-desktop pulseaudio[1516]: Failed to open cookie file '/ho>
Jul 04 10:16:15 roger-desktop pulseaudio[1516]: Failed to load authentication k>
Jul 04 10:16:18 roger-desktop systemd[1502]: Started Sound Service.

So I am not sure if it is working because when I enter: journalctl | grep pulseaudio I get:
Jul 04 10:16:15 roger-desktop pulseaudio[1516]: Failed to open cookie file '/home/roger/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
Jul 04 10:16:15 roger-desktop pulseaudio[1516]: Failed to load authentication key '/home/roger/.config/pulse/cookie': No such file or directory
Jul 04 10:16:15 roger-desktop pulseaudio[1516]: Failed to open cookie file '/home/roger/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
Jul 04 10:16:15 roger-desktop pulseaudio[1516]: Failed to load authentication key '/home/roger/.pulse-cookie': No such file or directory
and nothing for when the sound stops.

Comment: Paste the output of the following command (cut out the part that corresponds to the time of the dropout): `systemctl --user status pulseaudio` and `journalctl | grep pulseaudio`.      Paste the output into your question by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1252261/edit) it. Might help us!

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why but I installed "PulseAudio Volume Control" and as long as it is running the problem is gone.  If I close it it comes back.